# return value 3221225725 while experimenting with simple recursive function

Tags: c

While studying pointers, I was experimenting with the following simple recursive code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void test(void);
int main(void)
{
    test();
}

void test(void)
{
    int i = 4;
    printf("%i %i\n", &i, i);
    main();
}
```

output

```
...
4345292 4
4345228 4

--------------------------------
Process exited after 7.041 seconds with return value 3221225725
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Why it returns to value 3221225725. Does C run out of memory to store?
I was wondering why It only breaks after exact 32455 loops
(i am still in a learning phase, This is an experiment not actual code for any use. I purposefully made it break.)

Comment: Calling `main` in C++ is undefined behavior. Besides, this is endless recursion.

Comment: Calling `main`from `main` is a poor idea anyway.

Comment: It is a magic number, extra magical here.  Convert to hex and google the value.

Comment: A decent compiler would warn you about the `printf` argument mismatch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value 3221225725 (C00000FD in hexadecimal) is the error code for stack overflow on Windows.

The stack overflow happens because your recursion never stops. `main` is calling `test` which is calling `main` which is calling `test` and so on indefinitely until the process' stack is full and then Windows kills the process and returns the error code to the caller.

If you want to use recursion, you need a stop condition so the recursion will end at some point. Google "factorial recursion" for a simple example.

Be aware that recursion can be abused and often an iterative approach is more efficient.

Comment: @Agent_T the number of loops before it breaks depends on the size of the stack and a few other factors. On another system it might be slightly different. All you need to worry about is that stack space is a rather limited resource on any platform and that you shouldn't abuse recursion.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, in the part

```
  printf("%i %i\n", &i, i);
```

by supplying a pointer type as the argument of `%i`, you're invoking undefined behavour.

Change the code to

```
 printf("%p %i\n", (void *)&i, i);
```

That said, calling `main()` recursively is not a very good idea. Then, it's an [infinite recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Infinite_recursion), so you'll eventually encounter a [stack overflow.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow)

Use a loop if you want some actions to be repeated, with a proper terminating condition.